# open identity provider directly with FusionAuth

Tags: fusionauth

Im trying to make a button in my app that takes the user directly to the IDP, instead of going from my app to my auth provider where the user has to pick an IDP and then goes to the IDP.

I tried supplying the link with `identityProviderId` and the respective IDP ID, but that didn't work at all.

So how do I get the desired flow?

Answer (score 0):

This thread looks useful: https://fusionauth.io/community/forum/topic/229/how-to-open-identity-provider-directly

> I would use the lookup API to get an `authorization_endpoint` for the relevant identity provider. Then I'd have the button point directly to the `authorization_endpoint` rather than the FusionAuth login page.